# Force Validation error in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to force an error when using Validator Class in Laravel 5.1?

For now, I've done the traditional way calling `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules)`, which is working fine. Also, I'm attempting to make another validation (manual one) and push it into `$validator`, but I can't get `true` when I call `$validator->fails()`.

Even using `$validator->errors()->add('field','message')` I couldn't force it. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

In order to make validation fail, you need to define a validation rule that won't be met. Easiest way is to require some non-existent field.

This will do the trick:

```
$rules['some_non_existent_field'] = 'required';
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
dd($validator->fails());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too
**adding error to `Validator` doesn't make It to fail**, so you need to make a trap for It that forces It to, maybe a required input that doesn't even exist...
but that will make a confusing error for user (example: unreal_input is required),
 you'd easily change the message to explain what actually made you to fail the process...

```
$req = Request::all();
$rules = [/*...*/];

if(/*something's wrong*/){
    $rules['unreal_input'] = 'required'; // a confusing error in your errors list...
    $messages['unreal_input.required'] = '/* explain the real problem in here*/';
}

$validator = Validator::make($req, $rules,$messages);

if ($validator->fails()) return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

so in the code above you've manually checked if something's wrong, then you've made a trap for `Validator`, then you've changed the message to what the real problem was.

**NOTE:** I suggest you to use a random value instead of something like `unreal_input` , because If you do this, the user may(?) guess the input's name, and easily using **F12** he/she would pass the validation and give some invalid data to you